# How to detect variable change in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have the following config object which is set before the constructor is running:

```js
config: Object = {
     onSlideChangeEnd : function(slide:any) {
          this.currentSlideIndex = slide.activeIndex;
     }
};
```

I want to notify a service about the change, the problem is that the service is not available yet when the configuration is set:

```js
 constructor(private user: UserService,
             private layout: LayoutService) {
 }
```

How can I notify the service on this variable change?

Comment: Do you want to call the function on service? Plus, where have you placed the first code of block in your component?

Comment: Use an observable that notifies about updates.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer all best-practices I saw referred changes on Input() variables or http requests. How can I subscribe for a number type variable?

Comment: By using an observable. See for examples https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: This sounds like a huge overhead for the purpose of subscribing a single variable change.. isn't there a way to do it the same way of KnockoutJS observables?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, as suggested use Observables, this is not really such a big hassle and it works quite well. It's not more than a few lines actually.

Declare in some common service, a service that they share as same, e.g a service declared as provider in that module, so that you do not end up with two instances of the same service. Add a `Subject` to that service and a method to emit value:

```
public configObservable = new Subject<number>();

emitConfig(val) {
  this.configObservable.next(val);
}
```

And in the component you need to set the config:

```
emit(val) { // your value you want to emit
  this.myService.emitConfig(val);
}
```

And then subscribe to the value where you need it:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  this.myService.configObservable.subscribe(value => {
    this.value = value;
  })
}
```

Working plunker with above code in a parent-child interaction:

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bpl3vje178GsFIIMU7m5?p=preview)

As to your comment about `@Input()`, that works well when a parent component-child interaction, so that wouldn't really work for you in this case.

Comment: Works like a charm. I just want to add here that this works perfectly for bid-directional communication between components, too. I used in inside a modal to communicate with the webapp without failure.