# How to fire an http request if some shared observable's value got change in angular 4?

Tags: angular, forms, components

I am getting a form schema data in one component called Form component. Also I have one Edit and Add button on "Home component", where I am having all common things like sidebar, menu etc etc.

I want to know whether it is "Add" mode or "Edit" mode.and based on that I want to change the data passed to form view. For example if it is add mode then I want to pass only form data, if its edit then I also want to pass existing values.  To do that I have  shared variable called edit_status and add_status defined using shared service...

```
       private add_status = new BehaviorSubject<string>("not_active");
          add_status_message = this.add_status.asObservable();
           changeAddStatus(status: string) {
             this.add_status.next(status)
             console.log("just changed add_status",status);
           }
```

IN form component I am getting form data using http request like this.

```
     getJsonForm(){


        // I want to add condition here based on current value of add_status 

      let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.search = qp;

        this.http.get('http://example.org/url/Base/formfieldsgenerator_get?tabpgrpid='+this.tabpgrpid,{headers: this.headers}).map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
        res => { 

         this.FormData = res.schema;
        this.FormValueData = res.data;
          }); 
          }
```

Now as I have got the value of of add_status like this in Form Component which are transmitted by Home Component, How can I bind the variables in Form component to value of add_status and edit_status. IN other words how can I listen them and on changes of them I execute relevant logic.

Comment: is it possible to call/access one component's method to another (sibling) component's view?

Comment: found use full answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915625/how-to-detect-variable-change-in-angular2?rq=1